# get parent ID when an item is passed from a child object with angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I make a call to an API which returns data like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Past Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-08 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "6",
        "description": "6",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 6,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Bomb Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-10 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "10",
        "description": "10",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 10,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Each parent object also has a child object `(meals)` and a user can choose to delete any of the child objects `(meals)` and when that action is called it should be able to get the parent id as well. An example is when the meal object of id `27` is selected to be deleted, I should be able get the parent `id` which is `9`

HTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of menuList">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      {{item.name}} - {{item.servedate}}
    <h2>Meals</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let item of item.meals">
          <span (click)="removeMeal(item)">{{item.name}} - {{item.mealType}}</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
removeMeal(item) {
  alert(item.id)
 for (let s = 0; s < this.menuList.length; s++) {
  if (this.menuList[s].meals.length > 0) { // Iterate only if the array is not empty
    for (let r = 0; r < this.menuList[s].meals.length; r++) {
      if (this.menuList[s].meals[r].id === item.id) {
        this.menuList[s].meals.splice(r, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
 }
```

The code have the `id` I get in the alert is the id of the meal, but i want to get the parent `id` rather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following by renaming the variables of your `*ngFor` statements to make it clear which are top level items vs meals of `item.meals`. Then update `removeMeal()` to take in the the parent id value while passing in `item.id` into `removeMeal()` as the `(click)` handler:

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menuList">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    {{item.name}} - {{item.servedate}}
  <h2>Meals</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let meal of item.meals">
        <span (click)="removeMeal(meal, item.id)">{{meal.name}} - {{meal.mealType}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
removeMeal(item, parentId) {
  alert(parentId);
  // ...
}
```

Hopefully that helps!